# AWS - route 53 pointing to s3 bucket , Error is the alias target name does not lie within the target zone

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Full Error message - ***InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create an alias that targets s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com., type A in zone ----- , but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone]***

Trying to create route 53  new record and point to s3 bucket from  nodejs request

I have created a s3 bucket with same name test.mydomain.com

```
var route53 = new AWS.Route53({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region: region
});
let subDomainName = "test.mydomain.com";
let HostedZoneId = "idssss" (copied from route 53 where added mydomain)
var params = {
    ChangeBatch: {
        Changes: [
            {
                Action: "CREATE",
                ResourceRecordSet: {
                    AliasTarget: {
                        DNSName: "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                        EvaluateTargetHealth: false,
                        HostedZoneId: HostedZoneId
                    },
                    Name: subDomainName,
                    Type: "A"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    HostedZoneId: HostedZoneId
};
route53.changeResourceRecordSets(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);
});
```

What is the mistake here?
I am using same HostedZoneId two times , one is under AliasTarget , Is that correct ?

Comment: Suspect the `HostedZoneId` within the `AliasTarget` should be the S3 bucket zone ID, not the Route 53 zone ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AliasTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_AliasTarget.html) documentation indicates that HostedZoneId should be set as follows for an Amazon S3 bucket configured as a static website:

> Specify the hosted zone ID for the region that you created the bucket in.

You can find a list of S3 regional information at [Amazon S3 website endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints). The Website Endpoint for US West (Oregon) is s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com and the Hosted Zone ID is Z3BJ6K6RIION7M.

Also, see [Routing traffic to a website that is hosted in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html).

Note that after you make these Route 53 changes, they will be in status PENDING which indicates that the changes in the request aren't yet propagated to all Route 53 DNS servers. This is the initial status of all change batch requests. The status will change to INSYNC at some point to indicate that the changes have been propagated to all Route 53 DNS servers.

Comment: Yes , but where can I see HostedZoneId in s3 bucket page?  I have see any word "HostedZoneId" in s3 bucket crating process @jarmod , thanks in advance

Comment: Added hosted zone information.

Comment: Thanks brother its worked @jarmod  ,  but status is STATUS: "PENDING" in response is there way to identify everything is completed in API response

Comment: Added status information.