# AWS s3 bucket manage by aws-sdk in nodejs , Change aws s3 bucket public access from nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**How we can change aws s3 bucket public access from nodejs ? , see sreenshot**

I am able to create/delete and put/delete object with aws-sdk from nodejs , see below example code,
**but I want to unblock  "Block all public access"  while creating bucket or another new API request after bucket create** I have spent full day to find this solution but no luck[image]

```
var bucketParams = {
    Bucket: 'bucketname123'
};
    s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success", data.Location);
            updateWebConfig()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [deletePublicAccessBlock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deletePublicAccessBlock-property) function in the AWS SDK for JavaScript v2.

It will remove the PublicAccessBlock configuration for an Amazon S3 bucket. To use this operation, you must have the `s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock` permission.

Example:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  ExpectedBucketOwner: '123456789012'
};

const rc = await s3.deletePublicAccessBlock(params).promise();
```

Note that the Amazon S3 Block Public Access feature also provides an account-level setting to block public access that will override all bucket-level settings.

Comment: Seems worked , let me check detail

Comment: Thanks brother @jarmod , If you dont mind may I ask your skype/hangout , not asking for doubt I just want to keep the connection :) , anyway thanks

Comment: Hi @Hunter, apologies but I can't do that. I'm here on SO a lot though.

Comment: Could you please check this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77387978/aws-route-53-pointing-to-s3-bucket-error-is-the-alias-target-name-does-not-l

Comment: I think you can attend this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77532081/aws-create-a-s3-bucket-through-api-and-do-different-tasks-in-single-same-api-cal @jarmod

Comment: I think you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800427/taking-too-much-time-to-reflect-aws-route53-new-record-aws-sdk @jarmod