# AWS create a s3 bucket through API and do different tasks in single same API call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am able to create a s3 bucket in aws through aws-sdk API and make policy changes and do other changes , but I have to do different API call each tasks So my question is can I do all tasks in single API call ?

```
for create a bucket - await s3.createBucket(createBucketParams).promise();
for change WebsiteConfiguration - await s3.putBucketWebsite(putBucketWebsiteParams).promise();

for change bucket policy - await s3.putBucketPolicy(putBucketPolicyParams).promise(); 
for upload file - s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
```

Is there a way to do all sub tasks under created bucket in single API call?

Comment: You can technically do the first 3 in a single API call to cloudformation.

Comment: The [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html) does not support such a feature, so it's not possible.

Comment: There are a number of declarative [IaC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/introduction-devops-aws/infrastructure-as-code.html) solutions including CloudFormation, Terraform, Serverless Framework, SAM. If you prefer to write code to create the automation then you should consider using [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/) rather than an AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no. Like most APIs, when using the AWS SDK Serice Clients, you have to call a specific service operation to perform a specific task. You cannot call **createBucket()** and expect other tasks to occur.